# how can i directly access my web application deployed in aws tomcat using domain without showing port?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I Want to access my web application in the Amazon Web Service directly through my URL like Service.com but I am using tomcat so, I have to write port number with name Service.com:8090/Login.

Even if I set my port to 80 it will open the tomcat manager page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities for accessing your Application.

1- if you have deployed your application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Tomcat Beanstalk) then it will automatically route your application on Port 80 (default port for HTTP), you just need to configure route53 or can directly access the application via Beanstalk URL

2- if you have deployed manually, then you have to set a Loadblancer which will route from 80 to 8080.

Reference Link for Setting up Loadblancer:-
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-getting-started.html

While setting up Loadblancer your Instance Port will be 8080 and make sure your Inbound rule (Security Group) is configured  Properly.